# C# Usage of ZipArchive crashes the programm

Tags: c#, compression, zip

I'm trying to unzip files without providing an extra *.dll.
For that reason, i'm using the ZipArchive class from System.IO.Compression.

I added System.IO.Compression & System.IO.Compression.FileSystem as a reference and on my own computer, everything works fine. However, friends can't use it, because it crashes on the line

```
ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.Open(local, ZipArchiveMode.Read);
```

Do I need to provide an extra *.dll for it to work?
Whats the problem?

Comment: When it 'crashes', what exactly happens? Does it just stop working? Do you get an Exception? ... ?

Comment: How do you "distribute" your application to your friends' computers? Do they also have .NET version 4.5 installed?

Comment: They have 3.5 and 4.0..i totally forgot to check that..thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The [`ZipArchive` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive.aspx) you use is new in .NET version 4.5. From your comment to the question it seems that your friends do not have .NET 4.5.

The DLL in which this class resides, is `System.IO.Compression.dll` as can be seen in the documentation I linked, but you will not have to care about that if your friends install .NET 4.5 on their machines.